# Declare breaking and non-breaking symbols for breqn

Tags: breqn

How can I specify that a relation symbol is **not** available for breaking a formula? Furthermore, how can I specify that the punction `.` can be used as a breaking symbol?

Ideally I would like to write something like this:

```
\usepackage[breaking={.}, nonbreaking={\in}]{breqn}
```

Here is a minimal example formula that is indented weirdly:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{breqn}

\begin{document}
  \begin{dmath*}
     \phi = \exists x \in M. \exists y \in M. \psi
  \end{dmath*}
\end{document}
```

[image: broken indentation with breqn]

Comment: `\hiderel{\in}`

Comment: I think `\hiderel{\in}` is not the right solution. I want all occurences of `\in` to be non-breaking. Furthermore the documentation for `\hiderel` says that is should be used to prevent a relation symbol to be used as an alignment point and not for avoiding breaking of arbitrary relation symbols.

Comment: By default, `breqn` breaks at everything is marked as a relation. I never use it and never recommend it either.

Comment: But explicitly aligning and breaking your formulas does not scale either.